# logstash complete installation and configuration

Tags: logstash

```
sudo service logstash start
logstash started.
sudo service logstash status
logstash is running
$ sudo service logstash status
logstash is not running
bin/logstash -f trial.conf
bash: bin/logstash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please, suggest me the correct way to install logstash on ubuntu system and make it run

Answer (score 0):

Try this walk through https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

When it gets to the section titled "Configure Logstash" I simply do the following steps:

create a file in /etc/logstash/conf.d/ called 00-logstash.conf with the following content.

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 5140
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
    type => system
  }
}
   filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
sniffing => true
manage_template => false
}
}
```

in /etc/rsyslog.conf add a line in the middle that looks like this

```
*.*<TAB>@IPorHOSTNAME:5140
```

You will need to replace IPorHOSTNAME with your ip or hostname. If you're using the same system to read your information simply use 127.0.0.1.

In this situation you'll then run these two commands:

```
service logstash restart
```

and

```
service rsyslog restart
```

You'll then need to send all of your logs to syslog. You can do this by utilizing python (most other languages will do this as well.) and send strings to syslog. You can parse the information in the 00-logstash.conf file you created in /etc/logstash/conf.d/ using grok's.

If you have some other resource for feeding logs to the ELK platform, you can skip all the syslog config, and in your 00-logstash.conf file where input starts and says syslog, you'll research how to read from your log location.

Hope this helps.